# Is there an arbitrary precision floating point library for C/C++ which allows arbitrary precision exponents?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, arbitrary-precision

I'm looking for an arbitrary precision floating point library for C/C++ (plain C is preferred). I need arbitrary precision exponents. GMP and MPFR use fixed size exponents, so they are ineligible (I have some ideas for workarounds, but I prefer an out-of-the-box solution). It would be an nice feature if the exponent precision can be adjusted automatically to prevent infinity-values.

If you know for sure that such an library does not exist, please say so.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing as mainstream as GMP/MPFR as far as I know. But Fredrik Johansson's [arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/) contains a module called [fmpr](http://fredrikj.net/arb/fmpr.html) that provides floating-point numbers with arbitrary precision exponents.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty specialized request; without knowing more about your actual needs, I might consider using a more common arbitrary-precision library like MPFR to represent the logarithms of your values (which doesn't quite give truly *arbitrary* exponent range, but does get you exponents so large that it's probably no longer an issue).

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://www.ttmath.org/ - I don't think it can adjust precision on-the-fly, but it does support arbitrary precision reasonably well.